# CMFB - wide devices reduces voltage drop?

Tags: feedback

[image]

[image]

In the above CMFB using triode devices, one of the drawbacks is stated as being a limited output swing due to the drop of the triode devices (acting as resistors) M7 and M8.

It says in the hightlighed section that to reduce the drop due to this, M7 and M8 are usually made wide - **my question is, how does making a transistor wide reduce it's drop. I mean the output resistance is dependant on the length so why would voltage drop change?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I mean the output resistance is dependent on the length so why would voltage drop change?*

It is not about the **output resistance**, it is about the **DC voltage drop** you get across the M7 and M8.

NMOS M7 and M8 together have to conduct a certain current. Suppose that this current causes their \$V_{DS}\$ to be 100 mV.

Now what happens if we made M7 and M8 twice as wide, while keeping everything else the same. Would that \$V_{DS}\$ then decrease, stay the same or increase?

Note that **output resistance** is a **small signal** parameter. My story above is about the DC (biasing) situation, there is no signal present. I am not considering small signal behavior at all.

The same is true for the remark in the article, it is not about small signal behavior, only about DC.

Comment: Vds should remain the same? Isn't Vds dictated by the surrounding circuitry? I.e what ever I apply to the drain?

Comment: Why would \$V_DS\$ remain the same? I make the transistors **wider** and nothing changes? How can that be? Remember that M7 and M8 are in **triode mode** so they have a certain \$R_{DS}\$. If the \$V_{DS}\$ was fixed from the circuit, how would that work? Note that **only** M9 and M10 determine the DC biasing currents in this circuit.

Comment: Ah yes. The triode device is acting as a resistor and so a larger W will result in a smaller resistance thus reducing the voltage drop. So in the triode case -> the output resistance Rds is not a small-signal parameter but for a saturation MOSFET it is? Just a bit confused about why the Rds/Rout of saturation mosfet only applies in small-signal.

Comment: Edit: Nvm about that last question, Just had a look at the MOSFET I/V curve and it makes sense now. In triode there is a linear relation throughtout the entire triode region whereas in saturation, you need to have a small-signal zone to be able to approximate it as a linear relation.

Comment: Exactly, \$R_{out}\$, the **small signal** \$R_{DS}\$ is simply the **derivative** of \$V_{DS}/I_D\$. In saturation mode the \$I_D\$ is more or less flat over \$V_{DS}\$ so \$R_{out}\$ has a high value (kilo ohms to Mega ohms). But in triode mode the MOSFET behaves similar to a resistor so \$V_{DS}(I_D)\$ behaves as a resistor, and therefore has a linear relation. The derivative of \$V_{DS}/I_D\$ is then much lower, about the same as simply \$V_{DS}/I_D\$ or just \$R_{DS}\$

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much.